# How to I position something sticky so that it follows the screen in the center vertically

Tags: html, css, centering, sticky

As you can see in my snippet I have almost acheived my desired effect, by using `top: 50%;`. But is not exactly centered on the screen. If I add `transform: translateY(-50%);` I do acheive centering, however now the red div is position too far up initially and doesnt go all the way to the bottom. Anyone got any ideas?

(also please note that I cant know the height of this red div because it is supposed to be an image first of all, and second I need it to be responsive meaning the height will change)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.other_content {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
section {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 300vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
  /* transform: translateY(-50%); *//* DOES NOT WORK */
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="other_content"></div>
<section>
  <div class="sticky">
    <p>IMAGE WITH <br> UNKNOWN <br> HEIGHT <br> GOES HERE</p>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="other_content"></div>
```

Comment: IMHO that is currently not possible with CSS only. The problem is that there is currently no way to refer to the element's height, which would be required to achieve your desired result. You could think about solving it with JavaScript and custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 45%
  /* transform: translateY(-50%); *//* DOES NOT WORK */
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Just change the top percentage from 50% to 45%;

Comment: And how should that solve the problem if the image height is not known?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, can you change the top to 40% to make it higher? 45% (should) perfectly align it in the middle.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.other_content {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
section {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 300vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 45%;
  /* transform: translateY(-50%); *//* DOES NOT WORK */
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="other_content"></div>
<section>
  <div class="sticky">
    <p>IMAGE WITH <br> UNKNOWN <br> HEIGHT <br> GOES HERE</p>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="other_content"></div>
```

Comment: The OP says `I cant know the height of this red div` so only changing `top` won't solve the problem.